# Best way to create a data model with dynamic amount of properties in .NET

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, datamodel

I'm writing a data access layer where I want to return just the data required for each request. Let's say there is a total of 100 properties that you could retrieve, but a normal request will probably just need two or three of them.

So I've added a parameter to the request that specifies the properties you want to return and only this data will be pulled from the DB.

A normal request will return a list of 1,000 - 10,000 rows. My big concern now is how to return them efficiently.

The data will be used "internally" in my .NET-project but may also be serialized to XML and JSON, and therefore I don't want to have 98 empty properties when in fact there is just 2 of them that are populated with data.

So, what would be the best technique (in case of performance and "overhead size") to use for creating this model?

**Update:**
So a property could actually have three states. If it never was asked for, it should somehow be removed, and if it was asked for it should be either null or the actual value.

Comment: This depends on what kind of API you have in mind for your entities.

Comment: @Peter Forss: The number of entities is important, but just as important is how many attributes each of them has (in addition to any referenced entities per entity, and so on).

Comment: @Doc Brown: Hmm, what kind of API:s are there? This is kind of a generic data retrieval API where we will add properties continuously.

Comment: @casperOne: My bad, I actually meant rows, it's always (99.9% of the time) the same entity to the end user (even though the data may be retrieved from different tables in the DB).

Comment: @Peter Forss: It might be one entity to the user but how many attributes on the entity?  This can have an adverse effect on performance depending on how many attributes per row there are.  Or is it just one attribute per row, and all rows assigned to the entity?

Comment: @casperOne: That's the thing. At a maximum there is something like 100 attributes/properties but it all depends on what the user requests. And the average request will probably need about 2-5 attributes. All rows will have the same amount of attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree that [Andrei's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229912/best-way-to-create-a-data-model-with-dynamic-amount-of-properties-in-net/7230013#7230013) is convenient, it can definitely have a performance impact.  If your data is flat (and it is, since you are ultimately pulling from a database), then you can have an `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>` where each row in the [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) is a [`IDictionary<string, object>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) contains the values from the row.

It's a more unwieldy to begin with, but it *is* dynamic; the addition or removal of attributes from the result set will still work.

It's also more performant, in that you won't have `(1,000 to 10,000) * N` calls to reflection (1,000 to 10,000) rows, times `N`, the number of attributes on each row (if you have 100 attributes per row, then that's 100,000 to 1,000,000 calls to Reflection, which will add up).  The `DynamicDictionary` ultimately stores the key/value pairs in a lookup table, but it uses Reflection (optimized through the DLR, but that's still at it's core) to get to the lookup table.

And you *do know* what the properties are (you said you are using it internally for your project, so you *have* to know what the properties you want to use are).  To that end, you *really* should be using a strongly-typed [data transfer object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) with properties that are all nullable that represent the values from the database; anything that is null or doesn't exist in the result set gets set to null.  Values that don't exist in the result set never get set.

This way, you have no Reflection, you get compile-time type checking (which is *very* important, using `DynamicObject` will result in run-time exceptions), and better performance.

Serialization in XML or JSON is simple with either of these approaches, you simply serialize null values, or don't serialize the property at all (if using XML, just make sure that your schema supports the elements as being options).

Comment: +1 for the performance. But If I'm using a strongly typed DTO, how do I tell if that property was set or not? Because when I serialize the result to JSON/XML I want the property to be serialized even if it's null, so I need to distinguish between null and not set. I've considered using metadata for the properties, but that's also some overhead.

Comment: @Peter Forss: I'd disagree that your serialization has to have a property with a value of null.  That's what schemas are for, to define what the properties of the attributes.  Your schema would indicate that the data point could exist, but whether or not it *must* be populated is a different story.  JSON documents are never self-describing, and there is no schema for them, so their serialization format has to account for these inconsistencies to begin with.  Unless you have this as a formal requirement (which I would suggest you challenge)?

Comment: You are totally right, I thought that the Facebook API behaved the way I wanted it (to always return the fields you request) but when I took a closer look, It actually doesn't return fields that is null. (Compare http://graph.facebook.com/CocaCola?fields=founded to http://graph.facebook.com/Fanta?fields=founded). I will probably go for the strongly typed DTO solution.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `DynamicDictionary` (see the "Examples" section in the documentation for the [`System.Dynamic.DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) class) where `DynamicDictionary` is derived from `DynamicObject` class with ability to get/set properties in run-time.

It uses internal dictionary to store properties and their values so you will not end up with a lot of unused properties and access time should be fine. The usage is a very simple

```
    // Creating a dynamic dictionary.
    dynamic person = new DynamicDictionary();

    // Adding new dynamic properties. 
    // The TrySetMember method is called.
    person.FirstName = "Ellen";
    person.LastName = "Adams";
```

Or you can use [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) out of the box but it's a bit heavier because in addition to properties it allows you store events and instances of delegates here as well.

Serialization/Deserialization with XML/JSON should not be a problem here.

Comment: Looks nice! I've considered using ExpandoObjects, but I'm not sure about the performance. But if using any dynamic technique, DynamicObject seems to be the one.

Comment: +1, but I think it should be possible to enhance this for creating a class "Person" with type-safe properties, where each unused property does not consume any memory internally, but you cannot use any forbidden properties.

Comment: @Andrei Taptunov: Can't find the documentation for `DynamicDictionary` anywhere, are you sure it's in .NET?  Would you please provide a link to the documentation for it?

Comment: @casperOne: It's from the documentation for `DynamicObject` - just one of the examples.